# How to send a similar GraphQL query with diffirent ID's using Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using Apollo GraphQL in my React app.

For instance, I have a query

```
{
  files(id: 1) {
    name
  }
}
```

I've got 10 files and I want to get just one field.

As far as I know, I can't create something like this

```
{
  files(id: 1) {
    name
  }
  files(id: 2) {
    name
  }
}
```

It gives me an error.

I'm ready to iterate through id's [1,2,3,..10], but it looks like it's impossible using useQuery.

I'm stuck. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 1 query

```
{
  file1: files(id: 1) {
    name
  }
  file2: files(id: 2) {
    name
  }
}
```

or something like this if it support multiple parameter

```
query findFiles($files: [Int!]!) {
  files(ids: $id) {
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver!